# Missing folder from CloudBuild

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I am using CloudBuild for a build but find that its missing a folder I have in my local directory

```
/cloudbuild.yaml
/scripts
  /output
    .gitkeep
/...
```

One of my build steps writes to `scripts/output` directory. But it fails because its missing. It works when I create that directory first (`mkdir scripts/output`). Why do I need to do that? Whats causing the folder to be missing?

Comment: What the content of your files `.gitignore` and (if you have it) `.cloudignore`?

Comment: Cloud Build uses a directory named `/workspace` as a working directory. If your config file has more than one build step, the assets produced by one step can be passed to the next one via the persistence of the `/workspace` directory, which allows you to set up a pipeline of build steps that share assets. If you set the `dir` field in the build step, the working directory is set to `/workspace/<dir>`. More info can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config#dir)